# Xpath query on name rather than index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath

I have the following xml in an xml column in sql server, it is in a table along with a id column -

```xml
<ArrayOfExtVar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ExtVar>
    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Rate Code</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">E46</Value>
  </ExtVar>
  <ExtVar>
    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Middle Name</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Henry</Value>
  </ExtVar>
</ArrayOfExtVar>
```

And I have the following XPath -

```
SELECT CustID, 
ExtVars.value('(/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar/Value)[1]', 'Nvarchar(max)') AS RateCode,
ExtVars.value('(/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar/Value)[2]', ''Nvarchar(max)') AS MiddleInitial 
FROM dbo.Customer
```

which is great but what I'd really like to do is query the xml by 'Name' rather than the index ([1]) as these may be stored in different orders from time to time.

Basically what I need to know is how can I query by the value of 'Name' something like -

```
'(/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar/Value)[Rate Code]'
```

Could I add an attribute to the ExtVars Node and query on that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar[Name = 'Rate Code']/Value
```

Comment: Yes thats what I'm looking for but     ExtVars.value('(/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar[Name = ''Rate Code'']/Value', 'Nvarchar(max)') AS RateCode doesnt work. It's looking for an extra end bracket.

Comment: Sorry I checked, the xpath works on it's own but not within the t-sql syntax, have I put it together incorrectly?

Comment: @user1266921 you will either need _no_ brackets `value('/ArrayOfExtVar/....` or to do the same `[1]` trick with `value('(/ArrayOf..../Value)[1]', ...`

Comment: thanks, nearly there. This - ExtVars.value('(/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar[Name = ''RateCode''])[1]', 'Nvarchar(max)') AS RateCode returns not only the value I need but it also has the 'RateCode' appended to the front of it, ie. RateCode46 How can I seperate out the 46 to display on its own?

Comment: @user1266921 use the XPath I suggested in the first place, but with the [1] added i.e. `ExtVars.value('(/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar[Name = ''RateCode'']/Value)[1]', 'Nvarchar(max)')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (ID INT, ExtVars XML)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES(1, '<ArrayOfExtVar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ExtVar>
    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Rate Code</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">E46</Value>
  </ExtVar>
  <ExtVar>
    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Middle Name</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Henry</Value>
  </ExtVar>
</ArrayOfExtVar>')

SELECT
    Name = ExtVar.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    [Value] = ExtVar.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input
CROSS APPLY
    ExtVars.nodes('/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar') AS XTbl(ExtVar)
WHERE   
    ID = 1
```

Returns output like this:

[image]

And of course, you can add a name-based `WHERE` clause to this (that "reaches" into the XML to determine the result), too:

```
SELECT
    Name = ExtVar.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    [Value] = ExtVar.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input
CROSS APPLY
    ExtVars.nodes('/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar') AS XTbl(ExtVar)
WHERE   
    ExtVar.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE 'Rate%'   -- or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SQL Server's implementation of XPath supports the parent (`..`) operator, but you could try this instead:

```
/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar/Name[text()='Rate Code']/../Value
```

This finds the `Name` node that has an inner text of `'Rate Code'`, then navigates to its parent and from there it goes to the `Value` node underneath it.

---

If you could add `Name` as an attribute of the `ExtVar` node, that would make it a bit easier:

*Sample XML:*

```
...
<ExtVar name="Rate Code">
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">E46</Value>
</ExtVar>
...
```

*XPath:*

```
/ArrayOfExtVar/ExtVar[@name='Rate Code']/Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do axis steps in predicates, too.

```
//ExtVar[Name eq 'Rate Code']/Value
```